# What do you call a person who reads other's thoughts

Tags: single-word-requests

Need a one word that means a person that can read other from personal experience not like a psychic or a mind reader but like a wise person that knows when someone is lying or not acting like usual. Someone that can read right through other person's actions and know if they are up to something or what their objective is.
Is there such name?

Comment: There are tons of words that match your description...Please provide some context on how you are planning to use it to narrow down the choices.

Comment: Dont know how to say it better but ill think about it the last part is pretty close to what i mean "Someone that can read right through other person's actions and know if they are up to something or what their objective is"

Comment: Pedro... I suggest you to read the [tag info](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) and rephrase your question accordingly. People expect an usage phrase that will encourage them to answer

Comment: Sorry im new here gonna try to be more specific

Comment: Soulmate? BFFs? Therapist? Mentalist? There are plenty more I can think of.

Comment: @NVZ- +1 for "mentalist." Not widely in general use (except for the former TV show by that name), but a perfect word for what the OP is describing.

Answer (score 4):

[**perceptive**](https://www.google.co.kr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=perceptive+definition)

Google Definition

Adjective

> very good at ​noticing and ​understanding things that many ​people do not ​notice

Comment: That's a good one.  Acute might work here too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, ***perspicacious***

> Having or showing penetrating mental discernment; *also*, [**clear-sighted**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clear-sighted); [**clear-eyed**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clear-eyed). [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perspicacious)

Answer (score 1):

These may fit your description in a certain way.

***Discerning*** -- [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discerning)

> able to see and understand people, things, or situations clearly and intelligently; showing insight and understanding
>
> *"It's nice to meet someone with such a discerning eye."*

***Astute*** -- [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/astute)

> having or showing an ability to notice and understand things clearly : mentally sharp or clever
>
> *"He is an astute observer of the current political scene."*
>    *"Astute readers will notice the error."*
>   *"His analysis of the battle was very astute"*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a word yet, but there is a certain magical practice JK Rowling introduced in Harry Potter. It is called *Legilimency*, a way to infiltrate one's mind. It is used by Lord Voldemort to check the thoughts of his subjects, more importantly, his enemies. This is also a way for him to check if one is telling the truth.  The term for the person who practices legilimency is *legilimens*

Comment: The question specifically says "not like a psychic or mind reader".

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is **attuned to**: "especially able to understand or deal with".